OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: F:\deeplearning\model_segmentation\model\checkpoint.model.keras\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
I use GPU to train the model on Kaggle while  the code and dataset from the book Deep Learning With Python second edition.
the kaggle's tensorflow version is 2.15.0 and keras'version is 3.4.1.
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")
callbacks = [
 keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("/kaggle/working/checkpoint.model.keras",
 save_best_only=True)
]
history = model.fit(train_input_imgs, train_targets,
 epochs=50,
 callbacks=callbacks,
 batch_size=64,
 validation_data=(val_input_imgs, val_targets))

I want to save the best model using ModelCheckpoint and download it to a directory on my computer, and then use it in my computer's jupyter notebook.
In my local conda environment，tensorflow-gpu'version is 2.6.0 and keras is 2.6.0,too.
from tensorflow.keras.utils import array_to_img
model = keras.models.load_model("F:\\deeplearning\\model_segmentation\\model\\checkpoint.model.keras")
i = 4
test_image = val_input_imgs[i]
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(array_to_img(test_image))
mask = model.predict(np.expand_dims(test_image, 0))[0]
def display_mask(pred):
 mask = np.argmax(pred, axis=-1)
 mask *= 127
 plt.axis("off")
 plt.imshow(mask)
display_mask(mask)

then the problem comes.
This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, I would be grateful if anyone could help me
I have tried to downgrade the version of TensorFlow on Kaggle, but the GPU cannot be used with the lower version, which is obviously not what I expected

Your title and post text need some editing to make things clear. For example, your title doesn't match the code in your text. Why are there curly brackets? Where is the full error traceback? Please read How do I ask a good question?. Pay particular attention to where it says to share the full error. Furthemore, what is the following part about: "I have tried to downgrade the version of TensorFlow on Kaggle, but the GPU cannot be used with the lower version, which is obviously not what I expected"? It seems irrelevant given everything written  ....

 before that. Why does it matter what version is on Kaggle. Your post is about accessing the file you downloaded from there on your local computer and your local computer isn't recognizing the file, right? Maybe it will be a problem later but I don't think we can tell that from what you've provided. For now it seems like a path problem? But you aren't showing us anything to disprove that. Or more importantly, aren't showing us any indication that file you are trying to access is there. Where is a listing of the files at that point in the directory on the local computer? Have you ...

 established that in your computer's Jupyter Notebook you can open a file in that location? Make a simple CSV file on your Kaggle session and download it and put it in the same location and demonstrate you can open that with a very similar path. Also, back to the issue about the full traceback... You post a good size code block that you say you run on your local computer and then say, "then the problem comes." We have no idea where the issue comes in? You are supposed to post a minimarl reproducible example. From the weird text in the title, I'd suspect the problem is at the point...

 of the line `keras.models.load_model(....". And so we don't need a hug code block there? Unless maybe it is later? Either way in the first link I posted about  How to ask a good question, see the part about a minimal reproducible example. 'Minimal' is definitely important. Going back to my suggestion of trying to download and open a different file in that same location (by the way, I meant to suggest using Pandas to open CSV) ....Jupyter can be limited on the things it can access depending on how it is installed & where. Often it is easier to move a file to your working directory.
